# Equation for negative binomial regression from glm.nb() for use in program?

Tags: r, regression

I developed a negative binomial generalized linear regression model in R but now need to put it into Java. What equation do I use given these coefficients? (Sample below is just an example.)

As mentioned in http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/nbreg.htm

```
## glm.nb(formula = daysabs ~ math + prog, data = dat, init.theta = 1.032713156, 
##     link = log)
## 
## Deviance Residuals: 
##    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
## -2.155  -1.019  -0.369   0.229   2.527  
## 
## Coefficients:
##                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)     2.61527    0.19746   13.24  < 2e-16 ***
## math           -0.00599    0.00251   -2.39    0.017 *  
## progAcademic   -0.44076    0.18261   -2.41    0.016 *  
## progVocational -1.27865    0.20072   -6.37  1.9e-10 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it's the same as predicting from an ordinary linear regression result. You only need to apply the inverse of the link function in the end.

```
#some data to predict for
newdata <- dat[c(1, 200),]

#using the predict function
predict(m1, newdata = newdata, type = "response")
#       1      200 
#6.031207 2.259683 

#the manual way
logprediction <- coef(m1)["(Intercept)"] + 
  newdata[, "math"] * coef(m1)["math"] +
  (newdata[, "prog"] == "Academic") * coef(m1)["progAcademic"] +
  (newdata[, "prog"] == "Vocational") * coef(m1)["progVocational"]
exp(logprediction)
#[1] 6.031207 2.259683

#using matrix algebra
newdata1 <- model.matrix(formula(m1), newdata)
exp(newdata1 %*% coef(m1))
#[,1]
#1   6.031207
#200 2.259683
```